# Git: Default "no commit" merge behaviour for all branches?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-config

I want "git merge" to not commit by default (i.e., I want the "--no-commit" behaviour by default), regardless of the destination branch.

I know of "git config branch.master.mergeoptions" for a particular branch, and I know of "git config merge.noff no" for disabling fast-forward on all branches by default.

None of the following experiments work for me.  Should they?

- git config branch.mergeoptions --no-commit
- git config branch.*.mergeoptions --no-commit
- git config merge.commit no

Can't seem to find the answer via Google searches.

Comment: I'm not sure `git config` allows for wildcards like `branch.*.mergeoptions` - you may need to specify it branch-by-branch, which is admittedly a pain. Did you try the `no-commit` without the leading hyphens (e.g. `git config branch.mybranch.mergeoptions no-commit`)? Not sure if that's correct either...

Comment: You could workaround this by overriding `merge` with an alias like `merge=merge --no-commit`, not sure if this affects the commands done by a GUI though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I answered in the linked Question:

```
git config --global merge.commit no
```

I think the part which is of interest (you had tried almost the same) is the 'global' part.