# git merge with --no-commit as default

Tags: git, merge, config, commit

I am trying to set `git merge --no-ff --no-commit` as a default behaviour for merge.

Now I have read below questions:

[How do I make git merge's default be --no-ff --no-commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519007/how-do-i-make-git-merges-default-be-no-ff-no-commit)

[Git: Default "no commit" merge behaviour for all branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660529/git-default-no-commit-merge-behaviour-for-all-branches)

Following those answers, I added below to global config:

```
[merge]
    tool = winmerge
    ff = false
    commit = false
```

After adding new configurations --no-ff works correctly, but it still automatically commits. Then I searched for tried merge-documentation page:

https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-config/2.18.0

There is merge.ff entry but not merge.commit. I'm currently using git version 2.29.2.windows.2.

I added --no-commit to local config mergeoptions for a workaround:

```
[branch "master"]
    mergeoptions = --no-commit
```

It works for now, but I would like to have that behaviour default for all projects and branches on my pc.

So my questions are below:

1. Does merge.commit config really exist? If it is version problem, which version would allow this?
2. If merge.commit is not available, what would be the alternative?

Comment: Based on the answers you linked to in your question, try changing `false` to `no`

Comment: @J.Titus Sadly that does not work :(

Comment: I'd set an alias : `git config --global alias.mrg "merge --no-ff --no-commit"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `merge.commit` option: see [the source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e83ba647f7c61cf945690d6a0bd8c172a6498dc8/builtin/merge.c#L616-L668), where you can see which options are handled, and observe the lack of a `merge.commit` option.  There was no such option in 2014 either (clone and inspect the Git source to verify this, if you like).

The `merge.ff` option has been around since then, but `merge.commit` has, as far as I can tell, never existed.  You can of course run a command other than `git merge` to start merging, and by doing that, you can make this command supply `--no-commit` as an explicit argument.  Note, however, that you cannot alias Git built-ins, so there is no way to make a *Git* alias that inserts `--no-commit` when you run `git merge`.  Run `git mymerge` and make that a Git alias, or run `mymerge` and make that a shell alias, but do not run `git merge`.

(Your other option is of course to set `branch.name.mergeoptions` for every branch name.)

Comment: I really wonder where did they come up with merge.commit options...

Comment: @MarkSouls: I'm not sure precisely how these come about, but since you can `git config` anything you like (`git config dutch.anteater aardvark`) and nothing *complains*, I can see how some people think it must mean something to do that. And, when someone is flailing, they might try several things at once, one of which is the one that actually *worked*, and get the impression that it was something else that worked.

Comment: The one I really wonder about is `user.password`. Git itself does not and never has used this, but maybe *some* program *did*, the same way you can write your own program that checks for a `dutch.anteater` configuration variable.

Comment: That makes sense, maybe there is a third party gui program that does checks ```merge.commit```.